# How to print the whole lines of the interface based on value using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

```py
configuration="""
interface value is 3/40
    description eth/1-20-ugb-eth/58
    logging event port 
    ip address 34.5.62
    no downtine
interface value is 1/67
    description eth/4-56-ugb-eth/78
    logging event address
    ip address 5.7.8.9
    no downtime"""
```

expected output:

```
interface value is 3/40
  description eth/1-20-ugb-eth/58
  logging event port 
  ip address 34.5.62
  no downtine
```

here I need to print interface configuration based on my value.
if value is 3/40 then need to print particular configuration of the interface but am getting the all interface lines.Can any one please assist me regarding this.

my code:

```py
re.search(
    r"\b{0}(.*)\b".format("interface value{}".format("3/40")) + r"downtime",
    configuration,
    re.DOTALL,
)
```

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/n4OxZ9

Comment: "my code:" - does it not work? Please describe the issue

Comment: @Wiktor Thank you so much. it's working fine.